# Variable Assigned Boolean Values

Tags: python, types, boolean

I'm learning Python and there is a problem where I got stuck. I would definitely appreciate it if anyone can help to solve my doubts.

When I typed this code:

```
i=1 and i<=10 
print(i)
```

the output is True. Obviously i is a boolean now but I don't understand why.
For there is an "and", and 1 is less than 10, so the ***statement*** "i=1 and i<=10" is true. But why the ***variable i*** (rather than the whole statement) becomes a boolean? I thought i should still be an integer whose value is 1?

It's a beginner's question but it really confuses me. Thanks for anyone who contributes an idea!

Comment: That line reads as `i = (1 and i<=10)`. You are assigning the expression `1 and i<=10` (which is true) to the variable `i`.

Comment: you probably wanted to write `i == 1` instead of `i = 1`

Comment: If `i` has not previously been defined this code will result in a `NameError`

Comment: The statment is `1 and i<=10`. Its result is then bound to `i` as its the left hand side of the assignment operator `=`.

Answer (score 1):

By your code , I think that you are setting ‘1 and i<=10’ into your i variable.

If you want check equal to 1 , use ‘==‘ and add an if sentence, so your code will be:

```
if i==1 and i<=10:

    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement is to the right of the assignment operator `=`

```
1 and i<=10
```

`i` is not defined at this point in your example, so a NameError would be raised. I assume that you defined `i` somewhere before running this code and didn't see the error.

Had `i` been defined, the result of calculating this statement would be assigned back to `i` as it is to the left of the assignment operator `=`. Its the same as

```
i = (1 and i <= 10)
```

If you want to assign `i` before the comparison, then it needs to be in another statement

```
i = 1
i <= 10
```